# Text search in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, full-text-search

I went through threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73527/whats-the-best-option-for-searching-in-ruby-on-rails) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47656/how-do-i-do-full-text-searching-in-ruby-on-rails) for constructing a full fledged text search engine in RoR. But both these threads are very old (>2 years). I would like to know what is the latest and most stable fuzzy search engine that is compatible and used in rails. Links to resources/tutorials are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also popular at the moment is [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/). Database independent, but built by Apache, so a bit on the complex side of things. Luckily the Sunspot gem helps a great deal in making it easier to use. I would recommend you use a monitoring daemon with it (like [God](http://god.rubyforge.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.tech-recipes.com/johnny/2006/08/27/ruby-on-rails-using-full-text-search-with-tagging/ or you can also use Sphinx with Linux/Windows

http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/